# Not sure if my UML USE-CASE diagram is correct

Tags: uml, diagram, use-case, enterprise-architect

I've started learning UML but it confuses me sometimes (for example what i'm allowed or not to put in my USECASE diagram, last time i was wondering if logging in can be used in usecase diagram). Anyways i've made simple usecase diagram of e-learning platform, like lynda but you have to pay for individual course you'd like to take. Any suggestions/corrections about my diagram? (i'd like to bring more usecases into it)

[image]

Comment: why arrow **from** grade **to** student? why arrow **from** pay for course **to** payment system? why no arrow heads on `teacher create course`, `teacher manage courses` and `administrator manage users`? also, are you absolutely sure payment system is an actor? it could be so, but just really think about it!

Comment: I tought i had to point that grades are for students exclusively, i've also found my own mistake, that pay should be include not extend, since extend is optional. As far as i read pay system could state as person actor, i'm too new to be certain tho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would split that Usecase called `Register/Login` into two separate Usecases. I think these steps are two separate actions and need different steps to execute. This way you are also able to transform the Usecases to Composites.

We often do it this way:

- Create the Usecase
- Create an Activity Diagram with the same name
- Right-click on the Usecase
- Advanced
- Make Composite

Then you could add more detailed steps on how to implement/execute the certain Usecase in the Activity Diagram.

*This answer is specific to Enterprise Architect of course.*

Answer (score 3):

as you know, a use case is a textual representation of a flow between a user and the system. the use case should have a name that reflects that flow. when i look at your use case names i can see that you have understood this. the names are all descriptive and well thought through. well done!

so, about use case diagrams: the purpose of a use case diagram is to make it easier to understand what use cases there are, **and what type of users the use cases are intended for**. because of this, the arrows always go ***from*** an actor ***to*** a use case.

sometimes an actor can be a separate system, and then it should be included in the use case diagram as an actor, with a name that hints to the actor being a system. if a group of persons for some reason could have a name that include the word 'system', i think it should be clarified that the actor portraying that group of persons is not an actual system, although the name of the actor hints to it being a separate system.

Comment: Hello thanks for helpful answer. Thing is i kinda look at uml from my previous php (cms etc.) experience. And this experience starts to ask myself a questions like: should i assume that teacher is sort of a user that has to log in like student? Should i make him inherit from the guest? Can ,,watching or using the course'' be a case of use added to mine diagram? And if so should it be extended or independent? I'd like to make my diagram a bit more complex that it is already, but i'm not sure what am i limited to (since i want to make it correct with standards, good practise you know).

Comment: Also i'm not sure how to handle teacher's ability to make tests, should it be included in courses (with name?) or just leave it for now?

Comment: Do what communicates the solution you are looking for.  Often use cases require documentation behind them anyhow to really be useful, the diagram is a great overview and way to step into the expected solution.

Comment: A Usecase is goal oriented scenario.  Register and logon are separate goals and manage is not a goal.

Answer (score 2):

Login is not a user goal. Login is necessary to be able to satify the user goal of register.  If a user logged in, did nothing else, and logged out, what value does that provide? None.

Comment: Is there any definition of this value? Does log in and log out have a value to the system if such system makes money from contextual adverbs? And in other system, which makes money from payment announcements, the only use case having value is "Add announcement", isn't? And every other use cases like registering, login, adding comments, browsing announcements are valueless then.

Answer (score 0):

From a while I'm training basic skills in Software Engneering area and create small simple project where users will exchange offers without money. Apart of financial system. So I've just created some Use Cases with Diagrams on basic system scenarios and I want to ask You for a help to check. Is it quite good what I've created or I've here a lot of of particular mistakes. From the last couple months I read a book about Software Engeneering and this is a part where I try to create something practical.

UC 3. Adding offer of service

1. System display offer of service form
2. Contactor fill all require fields (name, description, price, expected execution date)
3. Contractor fill note field if it is necessary
4. User confirm the offer on the system
5. System register the offer on the database and assign an ID

UC 4. Modification of offer introduced service

1. System display list of registered service registered by performer
2. Performer activate editing offer option
3. System display information form concerning particular offer
4. Performer modify particular offer in proper way
5. Performer applying modified offer and confirm final modification window generated by the system.

If it's necesserly I can add functional lrequirements to better understand the idea of project.